# Text blits to screen at wrong y-coordinate

Tags: python, pygame

I have a program that is meant to scroll numbers/letters down the screen, like in the movie "The Matrix". When one of the columns reaches a letter in the user's name (obtained using user input), it freezes and all of the other characters in that column fade away. The program opens correctly,but will only print characters at a zero y-coordinate. This is the function which blits the letters and numbers to the screen. When I insert a print statement to check if it is printing the letter at the right y coordinate, it says it is incrementing by 32 pixels, like it should.

```
for sym in lst:
    symbol = matrixfont.render(sym, True, (0, 255, 0))
    print("Printing %s" % sym)
    print("x coord is %s and y coord is %s" % (x_coord, i))
    screen.blit(symbol, (x_coord * 30, i))
    pygame.display.update()
    i -= spacing
```

It just prints all of the letters at y-coordinate 0, but at the correct x-coordinates. Maybe the full code will help:

```
import time
import random
import pygame
pygame.init()

#----------DEFINING VARIABLES

user_name = input("Type in your first name.")
spacing = 32
symbol_list = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
               "V", "w", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
background_color = 0, 0, 0
master_list = []
matrixfont = pygame.font.Font("C:/Python34/Programs/MatrixSpeller/OCRAEXT.TTF", spacing)
pressedkey = pygame.key.get_pressed()
windowwidth = len(user_name) * 30

#----------SETTING UP WINDOW

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowwidth, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Name Speller')
screen.fill(background_color)

#----------DEFINING FUNCTIONS


def update_list(x):
    print("update list %s" % x)
    s = random.choice(symbol_list)
    lststring = master_list[x]
    lststring = s + lststring[:9]
    master_list[x] = lststring


def print_list(lst, x_coord):
    global i
    i = 0
    for sym in lst:
        symbol = matrixfont.render(sym, True, (0, 255, 0))
        print("Printing %s" % sym)
        print("x coord is %s and y coord is %s" % (x_coord, i))
        screen.blit(symbol, (x_coord * 30, i))
        pygame.display.update()
        i -= spacing

#----------MAIN LOOP

for n in range(len(user_name)):
    master_list.append("@")
    print("master list is %s" % master_list)

while True:
    for n in range(len(user_name)):
        update_list(n)
        print_list(master_list[n], n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you're subtracting from the y-coordinate `i -= spacing`.  In pygame, the upper left of the screen is (0,0) and the lower right is (width, height) so you should have:

```
i += spacing
```